# cast error and invalid conversion error

Tags: c

> error: cast from 'void*' to 'unsigned int' loses precision
>
> error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int**'

can u tell me how to properly cast this, i am getting error on this line:

> color = (unsigned int)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int));

inside the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;
unsigned int **color = NULL;

bool file_write()
{
     FILE *fractal = fopen("mandelbrot_imageSequential.ppm","w+");
    if(fractal != NULL)
    {
            fprintf(fractal,"P6\n");
            fprintf(fractal,"# %s\n", "Mandelbrot_imageSequential.ppm");
            fprintf(fractal,"%d %d\n", height, width);
            fprintf(fractal,"40\n");
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            unsigned int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
            for(x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                    for(y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                    {
                            R = (color[y][x]*10);
                            G = 255-((color[y][x]*10));
                            B = ((color[y][x]*10)-150);
                            if(R == 10) R = 11;
                            if(G == 10) G = 11;
                            if(B == 10) B = 11;
                            putc(R, fractal);
                            putc(G, fractal);
                            putc(B, fractal);
                    }
            }
            fclose(fractal);
    }
    return true;
}
int method(int x, int y, double min_re, double max_re, double min_im, double max_im, int max_iterations)
{
    double threshold = 4;
    double x_factor = (max_re-min_re)/(width-1);
    double y_factor = (max_im-min_im)/(height-1);
    double c_im = max_im - y*y_factor;
    double c_re = min_re + x*x_factor;
    double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
    unsigned int col = 0;
    for(unsigned n = 0; n < max_iterations; ++n)
    {
        double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
            if(Z_re2 + Z_im2 > threshold)
            {
                    col = n;
                    break;
            }
            Z_im = 2 * Z_re * Z_im + c_im; 
            Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;
    }
    return col;
}


void method1(double min_re, double max_re, double min_im, double max_im, int max_iterations)
{  
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                    int m1 = method(x,y,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,max_iterations);
                    if(m1)
                    {
                            color[x][y] = m1*50;
                    }
            }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     unsigned int max_iterations;
     int x,y;
     double threshold;
     double min_re;
     double max_re;
     double min_im;
     double max_im;
     unsigned int NUM_OF_THREADS;
if(argc != 10)
{
    printf("There is an error in the input given.\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    height = atoi(argv[1]);
    width = atoi(argv[2]);
    max_iterations = atoi(argv[3]);
    min_re = atof(argv[4]);
    max_re = atof(argv[5]);
    min_im = atof(argv[6]);
    max_im = atof(argv[7]);
    threshold = atoi(argv[8]);
    NUM_OF_THREADS = atoi(argv[9]);
    }
color = (unsigned int)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int));
printf("height = %d\twidth = %d\tmaximum_iterations = %d\tminimum_x-value = %.2f\tmaximum_x-value = %.2f\tminimum_y-value = %.2f\tmaximum_y-value = %.2f\tthreshold_value = %.2f\tno. of threads = %d\t\n",height,width,max_iterations,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,threshold,NUM_OF_THREADS);
for(x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    color[x] = (unsigned int*)malloc(width*sizeof(unsigned int));
}
time_t ts,te;
time(&ts);
method1(min_re, max_re, min_im, max_im, max_iterations);
time(&te);
double diff = difftime(te,ts);
file_write();
printf("Total Time elapsed: %f\n",diff);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This ain't C++ code, but C !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
color = (unsigned int**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int*));
```

Shouldn't it be this?

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of malloc in C.  It is pointless and can actually hide the fact that you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`.  C is not C++ in this regard.  A `void*` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type in C.

Comment: Sorry, the question was tagged C++ when I answered.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough... though you should have probably noted that the use of `malloc` is probably wrong for C++.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you casting the return value of malloc to an `unsigned int`?

First off, don't cast the return value of malloc in C. It is pointless and can actually hide the fact that you forgot to include . C is not C++ in this regard. A void* can be implicitly converted to any pointer type in C.

Secondly, `malloc` returns a pointer, and you have defined `color` as an `unsigned int**`... yet you attempt to assign an `unsigned int` as well as an `unsigned int*` to it.  Obviously those are incompatible.  Just drop the casts and use/declare the type properly.

Comment: actually here its the color variable is allocated in the memory allocated to the program...

Comment: @visanio_learner: I don't understand how that is relevant.  You declared color as an `sunsigned int**`.  Great, so the correct assignment would be `color = malloc(some_size)`.  No cast required, and one of the casts you have (unsigned int) would just be wrong in general.

Comment: friend, i can explain you, color = (unsigned int**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int*));
color is ** its a pointer. so what we are doing is malloc(some_size) is holding an value in that pointer which allocates memory space and then unsigned int** will hold the starting address of the value.

Comment: @visanio_learner: Thank you, but I understand how malloc works perfectly well.  I am not confused about that, I am confused as to why you would ever cast the result (as it is not needed in C and actually can be a bad thing) and also why you would cast to an incompatible type.

Comment: but it works for me, i got the output... i don't really get your point about this 'incompatible'

Comment: @visanio_learner: My point is the two errors you ran across that made you post a thread here... don't cast the return value of malloc in C.  Really, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate array of pointers dynamically. So what you need to do is the following:

```
color = (unsigned int**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Rest of it is fine ...